# fatal: Pathspec 'autoload_classmap.php' is in submodule 'module/CocktailMakerModule'

Tags: git

I have a repository on google code with my project.

I use Git source control.

It seems that when I try to add files to git from a specific directory, I get the following error:

```
fatal: Pathspec 'autoload_classmap.php' is in submodule 'module/CocktailMakerModule'
```

Now I'm not trying to add a submodule. I'm just trying to add a directory to git!

The result that I have now is that this directory is committed empty. So when I try to add specific files I get the above error message.

I checked and there isn't any other `.git` directory in that directory, so I'm really confused to why this has happened.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Still no idea how it happened. All documentation I read assumes I have a `.git` directory there but I don't.

I just did the following:

```
git rm -rf --cached CocktailMakerModule/
git add CocktailMakerModule/
```

That seems to resolve the issue.

Comment: This worked for me!. I was trying to add wordpress theme to my git repo when i got this error. Thanks again that worked! :D

Comment: I came to that situation by manually removing `.git` from a subdirectory. Only after I noticed that was part of a submodule. Really mangy issue this one...

Comment: I have .git and see it! But when I want to commit some files that located in a folder, it shows an error "blahblah did not match any file(s) known to git"

Comment: @ntd - same here. I manually removed a `.git` which lead to all sorts of problems! 

This fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

To remove unwanted submodule, you need to unregister it by:

```
git submodule deinit CocktailMakerModule
```

then re-add the directory or file again:

```
git add CocktailMakerModule
```

Check your current outstanding submodules by: `git submodule status`.

For further info, check the Git manual by running: `man git-submodule`.

---

Otherwise if you want to keep this submodule, please follow: [Git: fatal: Pathspec is in submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24472596/55075).