# yii2 datepicker is not working on a remote server

Tags: git, datepicker, yii2

I'm using datepicker (kartik) on my yii2 project. And it's working fine locally. But when I push this project to remote server via git it's indicating error like this:
[image]

Please share me if anybody knows what is going on here.
I've encountered strange thing. This is my git server:
[image]

And there is no this folder in my remote server. **yii2-widget-datepicker** folder should be included because Datepicker class is inside this folder. So, what should I do in this case?? What solution would be best??

When I try to add **yii2-widget-datepicker** in my local project an error comes:
[image]

Comment: I just found the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23612012/fatal-pathspec-autoload-classmap-php-is-in-submodule-module-cocktailmakermod

Answer (score 0):

you need to update the composer on your remote server.

> php composer.phar update

If you have committed the composer.json file then the datepicker widget will get included on your remote server

Comment: When I try to update remote composer as you say I've encountered an error: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in mysite/httpdocs/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-composer/Plugin.php on line 31`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forgot to import the class. Try

`use kartik\date\DatePicker;`

[Official Documentation](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker#usage)

Comment: No I didn't. I added class. But there was no Datepicker.php file which involves Datepicker class. When I pushed local project to remote server via git, one folder wasn't pushed. So I cleared a folder (which keeps Datepicker.php) from git and added one more time. This is the solution )))