# Heroku doesn't find my index.js, however my index.js is effectively in my directory

Tags: javascript, heroku, create-react-app

**Edit : [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23612340/9817602)   works for me.**

While trying to git push to Heroku as master, my console returns me that Heroku failed to find the client/src/index.js file, but in fact it is effectively in my directory.

My build works fine in local but fail when I try to push it in a Heroku production's environment.

So far I have make some manips as :

- commituntracked files
- git add -A
- delete .git folder of these directories.
- my .gitignore are clean, no `index.js` specified in'

But it still doesn't work. My console returns me :

> Could not find a required file.
>
> Name: index.js
>
> Searched in: /tmp/build_a371b974c2c8e8fdf83c4e7f613805b2/client/src

So what can I do, if anyone have an hint,
Thanks